# Does clever noise exist?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

This question is about a random noise, which is called *clever* if its distribution function satisfies a certain condition.

Let $Y_0$ and $Y_1$ be two continuous random variables on the same probability space, which are associated with two *distinct* probability measures $P_0$ and $P_1$ respectively. Let the probability ratio function  be $l(y)=p_1(y)/p_0(y)$, where $p_0$ and $p_1$ are the density functions of $P_0$ and $P_1$, respectively, and consider the (complemented) distribution functions of $l(Y_0)$ and $l(Y_1)$:

$$F_0(t)=F_{l(Y_0)}(t)=P(l(Y_0)\leq t)$$
$$F_1(t)=F_{l(Y_1)}(t)=1-P(l(Y_1)\leq t)$$

and define a function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ with the mapping $f:F_0\mapsto F_1$.

Now a clever noise $W$, a random variable with an **unknown c.d.f.**, is added to both $Y_0$ and $Y_1$: $Z_0=Y_0+W$ and $Z_1=Y_1+W$. Consider again the (complemented) distribution functions of $l(Z_0)$ and $l(Z_1)$:

$$F_0^W(t)=F_{l(Z_0)}(t)=P(l(Y_0+W)\leq t)$$
$$F_1^W(t)=F_{l(Z_1)}(t)=1-P(l(Y_1+W)\leq t)$$

and define a function $f^W:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ with the mapping $f^W:F_0^W\mapsto F_1^W$.

The noise $W$ is called **clever** if it violates the condition:
$$f^W(t)\geq f(t)$$
for at least some measurable set of $t$.

> **Question**: Does such $W$ exist independent of the choice of $P_0$ and $P_1$? In case the answer is negative: If $P_0$ and $P_1$ are also free to choose does $W$ exist in this case?

**What I think:** I think answers to both questions are negative. How to prove? No idea.